# How to run python program on command line with different input possibilities

Tags: python, python-2.7

If c is not know to the user and a = 3 and b = 2 I want to call the program like this:

```
$ python my_program 3 2
```

if c is know to the user and c = 9 I want to call the program like this:

```
$ python my_program -c 6
```

Since the calculation represented by `c = results.a + results.b` takes about 30 minutes complete I would like the ability to skip over it if c is known.

Would this be possible?  I have two different Code examples below but this is not exactly what I want.

**Code example 1**

```
import argparse

def my_function():

    if results.c == 0:
        c = results.a + results.b
        d = c + 5

    else:
        d = results.c + 5


if __name__=='__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('a', action="store", type=int)
    parser.add_argument('b', action="store", type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-c', action="store", default=0, type=int)

    results = parser.parse_args()

    my_function()
```

My code example 1 required calls would be:

`$ python my_program 3 2`

or

`$ python my_program 3 2 -c 6`

**Code Example 2**

```
import argparse

def my_function():

    if results.c == 0:
        c = results.a + results.b
        d = c + 5

    else:
        d = results.c + 5


if __name__=='__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-a', action="store", default=0, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-b', action="store", default=0, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-c', action="store", default=0, type=int)

    results = parser.parse_args()

    my_function()
```

My code example 2 required calls would be:

`$ python my_program -a 3 -b 2`

or

`$ python my_program -c 6`

Thank you for any help. Have a good day.

Comment: In your first example, set [`required=False`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#required) for all arguments? Also, I'd use a single `add_argument('ab', nargs=2)` for `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make all arguments optional and validate them yourself:

```
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument('-c', required=False)
ap.add_argument('a', nargs='?')
ap.add_argument('b', nargs='?')

args = ap.parse_args()

if (args.c is not None):
    # process c
elif (args.a is not None and args.b is not None):
    # process a and b
else:
    # validation errors
```

If you were willing to make `a` and `b` a single named parameter instead of positionals, you could use [mutual exclusion](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) to do this for you. Mutually exclusive groups require all parameters in them to be optional, and named parameters can only be required.

```
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()

g = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
g.add_argument('-ab', nargs=2, required=False)
g.add_argument('-c', required=False)

args = ap.parse_args()

print('args={}'.format(repr(args)))

if (args.c is not None):
    # process c
elif (args.ab is not None):
    a, b = args.ab
    # process a and b
else:
    raise Exception("should never get here")
```